# NSNumberFormatter-Decimal Style-value Changes when we again went to that text field, with or without editing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

The below code i used for formatting the string in *textfieldShouldDidEndEditing*,

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];    
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
long long num =  [textField.text longLongValue];
NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:num]];
textField.text = formattedOutput;
[formatter release];
```

I have an issue in above code is, first time its work normally but when we going back to the textfield , and coming out of it , then the value changes.

For example i entered value for first time is 123456789123456789
and got this output 123,456,789,123,456,789
and now when we re-enter and exit from the textfield with or without editing, i am getting the value is 123.

Thanks In Advance
Bhaskar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, because after first call in `UITextField` is stored `123,456,789,123,456,789`, not `123456789123456789`

When you are calling second time that method in `num` will be stored `123`.

Try this one:

replace

```
long long num =  [textField.text longLongValue];
```

with

```
long long num =  [[formatter numberFromString:textField.text] longLongValue];
```

Comment: Thanks alot, i have another issue, its accepting upto 18 digits only, because of long long value, my requirement is unlimited characters to be formatted, Thanks in advance

Comment: @Bhaskar i would ask your second issue (max 18 digits) as a separate question, since it's not related.